# how to push android project to github

Tags: java, android, git, github

open("gradle/wrapper/caches/6.1.1/scripts-remapped/ijinit_duzwis2ipqrhqcdf5qgg8bfpx/9fi4s0842i0sksg2m7izv32e4/cp_init3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87/classes/ijinit_duzwis2ipqrhqcdf5qgg8bfpx$_run_closure1.class"): Filename too long unable to index file

I have this issue with android studio , when I want push my project to github . when i want to add my file to vcs .
git -> add

I want to solve my issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to push my project from android to GitHub , while adding file to VCS this problem occurred in git add , i dont know what is the problem please give me solution.

Comment: What are you doing to get this error?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful.

`git config core.longpaths true`

Basic explanation: This answer suggests not to have such setting applied to the global system (to all projects so avoiding `--system` or `--global tag`) configurations. This command only solves the problem by being specific to the current project.